# How to change the axis of the plot titles in a ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, title

Does anybody know, how do I change the plot titles (annotated by the red arrow) to be horizontal in the following ggplot? And how do I move them to the left-hand side instead of having them on the right?

My code is as follows:

```
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(min(mdf["value"]), max(mdf["value"]))) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  xlab("Time (s)") +
  ylab("Channel signals") +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: A ridgeline plot might be more adapted to your data: https://r-graph-gallery.com/294-basic-ridgeline-plot.html#color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the side, use

```
facet_grid(variable ~ ., switch = "y")
```

To rotate the labels, add the following to `theme`:

```
strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0)
```

Comment: You are a star!! That worked. Thank you sincerely.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." upon clicking upvote. I accepted the answer however. Thank you again!